# How do I keep the lines with the highest number where a pattern is matched?

Tags: text-processing

For example, if my file looks like this:

```
string
string1
string2
string4
string800
value2
value3
value5
value10
something18
something20
```

I want the output to be

```
string800 
value10
something20
```

The word before the numbers could be anything, but when I said "where a pattern is matched" I meant that I want to keep the highest number where the word before the number is the same, for example, 800 is higher than 10 and 20, but I still want to keep the numbers containing 10 and 20 when the word before is something else than what was before 800, like in my example above.

I need this to work on OSX, so please avoid features that only exist in GNU utilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an osx `awk` to try this on, but it works on my linux gnu awk:

```
awk '
{ n = match($0, /[0-9]+ *$/);
  if(n){
    word = substr($0, 1, n - 1); num = 0 + substr($0, n);
    if(!(word in max) || max[word] < num) max[word] = num
  }
}
END{ for(word in max)print word max[word] } '
```

On each line we look for the starting index in the line of the regexp pattern that is a number with optional trailing whitespace. We split the line at that index into the word part and the number part. The number string is converted to a number by adding 0 to it. An associative array indexed by the word keeps hold of the biggest number.

Comment: Thanks. This did work on OSX. I do keep GNU awk on my computer, but it's more comfortable to have something that works on a fresh installation.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines corresponding to a given prefix are always grouped (i.e. all the `stringNNN` are together, etc.), you can use awk, buffering lines as long as they have the same prefix, then printing out the one with the highest suffix.

```
awk '{
    match($0, /[0-9]*/);
    current_prefix = substr($0, 1, RSTART);
    current_number = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH);
    if (current_prefix == previous_prefix) {
        if (current_number > max_number) max_number = current_number;
    } else {
        if (NR != 1) print previous_prefix max_number;
        previous_prefix = current_prefix;
        max_number = current_number;
    }
}
END { if (NR != 1) print previous_prefix max_number; }'
```

If the lines corresponding to a given prefix are not always grouped (e.g. you can have `foo1` `bar1` `foo2`), you can sort the file first.